# Equalizing volume of different songs in itunes

Tags: itunes, ipod, audio

I have enabled the option to [equalize volume](http://ipod.about.com/od/advanceditunesuse/ss/soundcheck_it.htm) but it doesn't seem to do anything. Neither does it work for itunes, nor for the songs on my ipod. Is there some option/setting I am overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use an external tool ([MP3gain](http://mp3gain.sourceforge.net/)) for this. It works fine without touching the mp3 coding. The linked one is windows only, but there is also a Mac version, if I remember correctly.

Comment: thanks, i will check it out. quick question, can i batch modify multiple directories that have about 10K songs :)

Comment: Yes, that is possible. It even has a feature for live albums or albums where the tracks have no pauses or crossfade. It can analyse the volume for the whole CD (folder) and then lower/raise the volume for each track by the same amount.

Comment: FYI, in the same vein than mp3gain batch editing, i wrote an Automator action that I use to automatically compute Replay gain for my incoming mp3 files. Check it here : https://github.com/KraYmer/MacMP3Gain-Automator-Action